# Deploying AWS Lambda using AWS SAM in Jenkins

Tags: python, scala, amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-sam

Background :
In our project we are doing bulk deployment in that we are having around 10 AWS Lambda functions, Few Scala applications and few configuration files. Currently we are deploying 10 lambdas if there is no change as well.

Problem :
Lets say we have changed code in Scala class, committed to GIT and from there using Jenkins we are deploying the changes. As we have no differentiation between Lambda and Scala changes we are deploying all the Lambdas, Scala classes and Configuration files as well.

Question :
My question here is if we implement SAM on top of our Lambdas and then will separate it out deploying all the lambdas at a time as a separate Jenkins pipeline. If there is a change for 1 Python code in Lambda functions will it allow to deploy only delta Lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

`sam deploy` will only deploy resources if they have changed.  Otherwise it noops (no operation).

Answer (score 0):

You always have to deploy the entire stack using `sam deploy`. If some of your lambdas don't have changes, then `--no-fail-on-empty-changeset` will be your new friend.